# possibility of using a function to calculate sum in vim

Tags: vim

I have some parameters in a text file which goes as follows

```
parameter1  =5
parameter2=4
----------
---------
parameter(n-1) = 6
parameter(n)=11
```

My requirement is that the values of the parameters should sum upto 100 and there can be number of parameters. I was wondering if I could write a function in Vim , which could calculate the sum and display it somewhere?
  I have no idea how to pass arguement to such a function,I was thinking it could somehow be done by block selecting the lines with parameter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following function to your `vimrc` file:

```
function! CustomSum()
        let sum = 0
        for l in range( 1, line('$') )
                let fields = split( getline(l), '\s*=\s*' )
                if ( len( fields ) != 2 || fields[1] =~? '\D' )
                        continue
                endif
                let sum = sum + fields[1]
        endfor
        return sum
endfunction
```

And run it:

```
:echo CustomSum()
```

That with your input data yields:

```
26
```

---

**EDIT** to add a range to previous function. Now accepts a range as input parameters named `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`. I increment them with `0` to convert them to integers, otherwise the `range` function complains. Last line echoes the result for debugging but would be better idea to handle the result in a return call (only uncomment it).

```
function! CustomSum() range
        let sum = 0
        for l in range( a:firstline + 0, a:lastline + 0 )
                let fields = split( getline(l), '\s*=\s*' )
                if ( len( fields ) != 2 || fields[1] =~? '\D' )
                        continue
                endif
                let sum = sum + fields[1]
        endfor
        echo sum
        "" return sum
endfunction
```

Now you can do visually selection or normal ranges, like:

```
:'<,'>call CustomSum()
```

or

```
:1,5call CustomSum()
```

Both should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I wanted to know how to pass parameter to the function.For instance , the parameter list could change , and the list could apperar in between other text.Is there a way to pass arguement to the function by selecting the suitable text ?

Comment: @Gautam: I've edited the answer to calculate the sum based in a range of lines passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a (pseudo) one-liner as well:

```
:let s=0
:g/parameter\d\+\s*=\s*\d\+/let s+=matchstr(getline('.'), '\d\+\s*$')
:echo s
```

It you want a function you fall back to [Birei's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400559/15934)

EDIT: BTW, we can also echo it directly with:

```
echo eval(join(map(filter(getline(1,'$'), 'v:val =~ "=\\s*\\d"'), 'matchstr(v:val, "=\\s*\\zs\\d\\+")'), '+'))
```

or if you prefer a command:

```
command! -nargs=0 -range=% Sum echo eval(join(map(filter(getline(<line1>,<line2>), 'v:val =~ "=\\s*\\d"'), 'matchstr(v:val, "=\\s*\\zs\\d\\+")'), '+'))
```